# How to pass enviroment variables using docker run command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using `docker` for deploying my applications and I need to pass environment variables in the docker `run` command. I'm trying to do that like the following:

```
docker run -it --env-file /path/env.properties --env my_var=rrree  imageName
```

and in the `Dockerfile` I'm trying to check if these variables exist using the following code in the `Dockerfile`:

```
cmd echo "test" ; echo ${my.var}
```

but when I'm running `docker run` command I have the following output:

```
test
/bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution
```

What do I do wrong? Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Share the Dockerfile and do give more information.

Comment: Shell variable names can't have `.` in them; do you mean `echo ${my_var}` with an underscore in the command?

Comment: typo issue like @DavidMaze said. `cmd echo "test" ; echo ${my_var}`

Comment: @David Maze thanks for the help its work well for me